# How to identify client type in Exchange 2010 c#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010, exchange-transport-agents

I faced with a need to identify client type in Exchange 2010 in my current work project.

In my scenario I have Exchange agent which observe mailflow on Exchange server. If incoming email message has attachments of some type (for example, MS Word) agent need to perform special actions acording to client type (Outlook, OWA, mobile client,...).

Surfing the Internet I came up with an ability to get this information using Exchange Management Shell command which gets this information from Message Tracking Log.

But I wondering is there any way to do it via C# in my Exchange agent.